# PHP How to adjust price in cart system with form field and button

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

Im trying to create a cart system for a store where the customer can choose to pay what they wish for each given product.

[image: http://imgur.com/CayqGsh]

I have a recommended price set per product in the mysql database which I dont want them to be able to adjust, but I do wish for them to be able to type in a new price in the text field in the cart and click change and the cart total and the form value etc changes to reflect this but im not having any luck. Heres my form code:

```
$cartOutput .= '<td><form action="cart.php" method="post">
            <input name="price" type="text" value="' . $price . '"     size="4" maxlength="6" />
            <input name="adjustPrice' . $item_id . '" type="submit" value="change"/>
            <input name="id_to_adjust" type="hidden" value="'. $item_id .'" />
            </form></td>';

$cartTotal=$price + $cartTotal;


$cartTotal = "Total Price : &euro; ". $cartTotal ." EURO";
```

just not sure what I should be typing in the php code block for when this change button is pressed, have tryed this but to no avail.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['id_to_adjust']) && $_POST['id_to_adjust'] != ""){

        $id_to_adjust = $_POST['id_to_adjust'];
        $price = $_POST['price'];

?>
```

any help appreciated.

EDIT:: Have uploaded a new image to better define the problem Im having.

Comment: what error are you getting, you did not mention that. What is the issue

Comment: What does "no  avail" mean in that case? If you have the posted values in those variables you need to access the DB in the next step I guess. (FirstQuestionReview)

Comment: Well im not actually getting any php error. Its just that when I click on change to adjust the cart total price with the new price entered in the text field nothing happens?

Comment: @eckes Im not even sure if I do have the posted values in those variables and if I do Im not sure where to go next to update the total price of the cart.

Comment: @user3123672 your question is unclear,that's why you arent getting answers. I suggest you to edit your post to make it clearer

Comment: have uploaded a better image explaining the problem, I basically just dont know how to update the price variable with the new one entered by the customer in the price field when the change button is clicked beside that particular song.